# Why does create2 predicted address not equal actual address?

Tags: solidity, create2

For some reason the predicted/pre-computed address is not equal to the actual address when the created contract accepts `address` for it's constructor parameters, however it's fine when the constructor parameters are `uint`. I've demonstrated both examples in the script below.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Factory {

    // example 1:
    function createTest1(uint number1, uint number2) public {

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(number1, number2));

        // source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#salted-contract-creations-create2
        address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            bytes1(0xff),
            address(this),
            salt,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                type(Test1).creationCode,
                number1,
                number2
            ))
        )))));

        Test1 test1 = new Test1{salt: salt}(number1, number2);
        require(address(test1) == predictedAddress); // Does NOT revert
    }

    // example 2:
    function createTest2(address address1, address address2) public {

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address1, address2));

        address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            bytes1(0xff),
            address(this),
            salt,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                type(Test2).creationCode,
                address1,
                address2
            ))
        )))));

        Test2 test2 = new Test2{salt: salt}(address1, address2);
        require(address(test2) == predictedAddress); // Does revert
    }    
}

contract Test1 {

    uint public number1;
    uint public number2;

    constructor(uint _number1, uint _number2) {
        number1 = _number1;
        number2 = _number2;
    }
}

contract Test2 {

    address public address1;
    address public address2;

    constructor(address _address1, address _address2) {
        address1 = _address1;
        address2 = _address2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason the predicted/pre-computed address is not equal to the
> actual address when the created contract accepts address for it's
> constructor parameters, however it's fine when the constructor
> parameters are uint

That's because you are not using `abi.encode` on the arguments but `abi.encodePacked`. As `abi.encode` pads the elements to 32 bytes there is no difference if your parameters are already 32 bytes long, as uint. In the case of `address` the missing padding leads to different output.

A more generic and correct version would therefore be :

```
  address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        bytes1(0xff),
        address(this),
        salt,
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            type(Test2).creationCode,
            abi.encode(address1, address2) // <-- abi.encode the parameters
        ))
    )))));
```

> I managed to get it working, all I had to do was cast the address to
> uint

Yes, because you implicitely called `abi.encode` on the parameters as `abi.encode(address_variable)` is exactly the same output as `uint(uint160(address1))` it's just a special case that won't work with types longer than 32 bytes, while using `abi.encode` will always work as it will always produce the exact deployement bytecode + abi.encoded parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense, once I’ve verified it I’ll approve.

Comment: No problem, I tested it with several types so you shouldn't encounter any problem, otherwise let me know and I'll edit / clarify any point that requires it. On a side note I suppose you got confused by the solidity documentation that doesn't state that arguments should be abi encoded, I opened an issue (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12811) and a pull request (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/12810) to change that since they definitely should be abi encoded.

Comment: The PR has been merged, so this will be reflected in the docs at the next version. Arguments must be abi encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be complete

with current solidity compiler CREATE2 can be called without using assembly with the following code

With constructor parameters

```
bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(parameter0, parameter1));
ImportedContract token = new ImportedContract{salt: salt}(parameter0, parameter1); // Use create2
```

Without constructor parameters

```
bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(parameter0, parameter1));
ImportedContract token = new ImportedContract{salt: salt}(); // Use create2
```

There is no need for the complex assembly code.

Comment: Nice tip. I had an issue with the use of `create2()`: I could not deploy twice the same contract (even if I changed the parameter values): https://gist.github.com/aguidis/43323920c76cc29898c38a7c3dce28f4

With your approach, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `create2` method Instead of `new` keyword.

Try this :

```
 function createTest2(address address1, address address2) public {
        address addr;
        bytes32 _salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address1, address1));
        bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodePacked(
                type(Test1).creationCode,
                abi.encode(address1,
                address2)
            );
        address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            bytes1(0xff),
            address(this),
            _salt,
            keccak256(bytecode)
        )))));

       
        assembly {
            addr := create2(
                callvalue(), // wei sent with current call
                // Actual code starts after skipping the first 32 bytes
                add(bytecode, 0x20),
                mload(bytecode), // Load the size of code contained in the first 32 bytes
                _salt // Salt from function arguments
            )

            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
        require(addr == predictedAddress); // Does revert
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, would you happen to know what the issue is with the other notation?

Comment: I can't understand which other notation are you talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, all I had to do was cast the `address` to `uint` as shown below:

```
function createTest2(address address1, address address2) public {

    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(address1, address2));

    address predictedAddress = address(uint160(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        bytes1(0xff),
        address(this),
        salt,
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            type(Test2).creationCode,
            uint(uint160(address1)),
            uint(uint160(address2))
        ))
    )))));

    Test2 test2 = new Test2{salt: salt}(address1, address2);
    require(address(test2) == predictedAddress); // No longer reverts
}
```